# Django - request POST

Tags: django, post, request

Shall I use (and why?):

```
if request.POST
```

or:

```
if request.method == 'POST'
```

Is there any differences except syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to check the request method, use `if request.method == 'POST'`.

`request.POST` is the post param dict, and you shouldn't count on its existence or lack thereof when it comes to the request method. (e.g. a post request with no params fails on that test.)

> Explicit is better than implicit. -- PEP 20, Zen of Python